# How to open an SQLite file with java.util.HashMap in the header?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have an SQLite db file that I tried to open but not matter what program I try to open it with, it fails and says that it isn't an sqlite file. After opening in a hex editor, the header says `java.util.HashMap` and `java.util.ArrayList` but the file name is `fullindex.db`. How can I open this file to view it's contents? I've never seen an sqlite db file with those lines in the header before so I'm stumped. This file is supposed to be just general information but I didn't know you could create an sqlite file in android with a HashMap or ArrayList. Any ideas?

**This is what the beginning of the file looks like**

```
¬í sr java.util.HashMapÚÁÃ`Ñ F
```

loadFactorxp?@  w      t fsq ~  ?@  w   @   t fsr java.util.ArrayListxÒ™Ça I sizexp   w   sq ~  ?@  w      t idt 4t wt freexsq ~  ?@  w      q ~ t 6q ~ 
t forcesxsq ~  ?@  w      q ~ t 8q ~ 
t fromxsq ~  ?@  w      q ~ t 16q ~ 
t

Comment: Looks like it is not a SQLite file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried opening it in SQLite Manager?

I typically use the Firefox Add-On to open SQLite Manager then try to open the file from there. You should be able to view the contents there.

UPDATE: You must use ESR(Extended Support Release) version of FireFox. You will probably need to convert the file to a .sqlite as seen in the other answer as well.

Comment: Unfortunately that extension doesn't work with the latest version of firefox :/

Comment: there is an ESR version of firefox that allows you to use the extension still